# How do I get the source code for just the ext4 file system on a Windows machine?

Tags: 13.10, ext4, source-code

I'd like to get the source of the just the ext4 file system, but from on a Windows machine. At the moment I've navigated to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/, but everything I've found doesn't make sense, and what I've downloaded thus far has been files with listings in them and such.

What's the easiest way to get the source code for the file system that Ubuntu is based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/files/e2fsprogs/ for the download.   Extract it with http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bzip2.htm

http://www.bullopensource.org/ext4/files/ext4.txt may provide some useful insight, but if you don't want to reinvent the wheel and need ext4 on Windows try the [http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/ Paragon ExtFS driver for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/)